# What arguments are required?

Tags: php, debugging, syntax

I have the following code and when I call `<?php compare_update ?>` I get a PHP error that tells me I'm missing argument 1.  Looking at the code can someone tell me what the variable for argument 1 is supposed to be?

```
function compare_update( $post_id ) {
    //Assign Posts to Variables
    $start = $_POST['_date_start'];
    $end = $_POST['_date_end'];

    //Parse Start Date
    if($start):
        $start = explode('-', $start);
        $start = mktime($hour, $_POST['_date_minute'], 0, $start[0], $start[1], $start[2]);
        $compare = date('ymd', $start);
    endif;

    //Parse End Date
    if($end):
        $today = date('ymd');
        $end = explode('-', $end);
        $end = mktime($hour, $_POST['_date_minute'], 0, $end[0], $end[1], $end[2]);

        // If today's date is within the date range of an event that spans multiple days & the event is NOT YET PAST
        if ((date('ymd',$start) < date('ymd',$end)) && (date('ymd',$end) >= $today) ){
            // and the start date is before today
            if (date('ymd',$start) < $today){
                $compare = date('ymd'); //Overwrite start date $compare
            } else {
                $compare = date('ymd', $start);
            }
        } else {
            $compare = date('ymd', $start);         
        }
    endif;      

    //Check if values exist and then update
    if($end):
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_end', $end);
    else:
        if($start)update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_end', $start);
    endif;
    if($start)update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_start', $start);
    if($compare)update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_compare', $compare);

    if($echo): echo $compare; else: return $compare; endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to `compare_update()`?

You need to pass it the `$post_id`.

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with WordPress how would I pass it the $post_id dynamically rather than static?

Comment: @Brian - You should incorporate that into the question, or ask a separate question.

Comment: @Brian: You would need to edit your question to include details of where you are calling the function from.

Comment: Took me a while but I did figure it out... Thanks to you for your help kudos for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your function says:

```
function compare_update( $post_id ) {
```

Yet you don't call it with any argument, like:

```
compare_update('100'); // Or some number/id/whatnot,
                       // more than likely a $_POST['id']
                       // or $_GET['id'] variable
```

When you create a function in PHP with arguments, and you don't give a default value within the argument list, you have to provide a corresponding variable within the function call for each argument that requires an input.

```
// $post_id is an argument
function compare_update( $post_id ) { 
    ... your code ...
}
```

So now you've created a function that requires one parameter be passed in the function call, which then is usable by that label within the function.

```
$post_id = $_POST['id'];
compare_update($post_id); // This is passing a parameter
```

For instance, you're using it down towards the end of the function:

```
//Check if values exist and then update
if($end):
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_end', $end);
else:
    if($start)update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_end', $start);
endif;
if($start)update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_start', $start);
if($compare)update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_compare', $compare);

if($echo): echo $compare; else: return $compare; endif;
```

Also, your code formatting is confusing. For instance, the code directly above could be:

```
//Check if values exist and then update
if ($end) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_end', $end);
} else {
    if ($start) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_end', $start);
    }
}
if ($start) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_start', $start);
}
if ($compare) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_date_compare', $compare);
}
if ($echo) {
    echo $compare;
} else {
    return $compare;
}
```

Comment: A good deal better than my answer, hope he looks here instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending `compare_update` a parameter? Like this:

```
compare_update($someNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's supposed to be the post id?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Except it was the answer... and not a comment. Are you upset I didn't state it authoritatively?

Comment: If it is an answer it should be phrased as such, yes.  It shouldn't be a question if you aren't actually asking a question.  If you are actually asking a question it should be a comment.  Additionally, answers should be more comprehensive, that explains something about what is going on, includes examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In other words,

<?php compare_update($id); ?>

where $id was set to the post_id you wish to compare_update to.